# Subsequent calls to File.listFiles on non accessible File object on network drive give different results

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
File file = new File("\\\\somenetworkshare\\folder\\subfolder");
System.out.println(file.listFiles());
System.out.println(file.listFiles());
System.out.println(file.listFiles());
```

Now, the subfolder is a directory that is inaccessible by me as a user. According to the Java 6 documentation File.listFiles shoulds return null.

I would expect the outcome of the above program to be:

```
null
null
null
```

Instead, the outcome is:

```
null
[Ljava.io.File;@6b86768e
[Ljava.io.File;@48d19bc8
```

In fact, it seems that for every call to listFiles after the first one, an empty Array is returned.

Is this a bug in Java or does anybody have any clue why this behavior exists?

My Java version is:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, and it is located in the native code of the FileSystem class.

A workaround is available by using the Files class and the newDirectoryStream method:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("\\\\somenetworkshare\\folder\\subfolder");
DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
```

If you don't have access to the folder, you will get a proper java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException